# What is .GPX Mime Type?

Tags: android, mime-types

I'm trying to save file in `.gpx` format.

So it's `xml` subtype.

`ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()` contract that i use telling me that `mime type` is needed because wildcard method deprecated. If i will set `text/xml` mime type my file getting saved with `.xml` type but i need `.gpx`.

I tried to find `gpx` mime type but looks like it doesn't exist.

i'm using registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) to pick file from system explorer. To start this launcher we need to call picker.launch(MIME_TYPE) and set mime type inside. So i'm trying to set application/gpx+xml mime type and can't pick my created files because they have different type. I just logged and found that they have text/xml tag.

So which type should i use to?

```
private val openPointDocumentLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri ->
        uri?.let { readPointsFromFile(uri) }
    }

    private val exportFilePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument("which should i use here?")
    ) { uri ->
        uri?.let { writePointsToFile(uri) }
    }

binding.btn1.setOnClickListener { exportFilePickerLauncher.launch("my_file_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.gpx") }

binding.btn2.setOnClickListener { openPointDocumentLauncher.launch(arrayOf("which mime type we using?")) }

fun writePointsToFile(source: Uri) {
        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(source, "w")?.bufferedWriter()?.use { stream ->
      val xmlString = // formin GPX string right here
      stream.write(xmlString)
   }
}

suspend fun readPointsFromFile(source: Uri) {  
   context.contentResolver.openInputStream(source)?.use { inputStream ->
       // dealing with picked file right here
   }             
}
```

Comment: Try application/gpx and application/gpx+xml.

Comment: @blackapps it's working for impoting but if i will set this when trying to open document - i cannot click on .gpx files. Can we somehow make only .gpx enabled to click or we should instead use mime type to be able to click on any xml files?

Comment: I see no code. You should realize that we might be willing to do some tests for you fiddling around with your code. For that we want to see code that we can copy/paste. A minimal reproducable example. We will not type that in...

Comment: @blackapps got you. will be added

Comment: @blackapps i found that `application/octet-stream` working. found it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format in `internet media type` alternate version